# Regex: Match 2 starts with the last sign from match 1

Tags: regex

is it possible to write a regex where the last sign from match 1 is the start sign of match 2?
I like to match all numbers between brackets and separated by a pipe. The situation is also complicated by the fact that, the match can only have one group deep.

This is my string: `Text (1234|5678|901) Text (222) Text (333|444)`

And I like to get:

- 1234
- 5678
- 901
- 222
- 333
- 444

But the regex schouldn't match:

- `Text (123 Text`
- `Text |123) Text`
- `Text |123 Text`

I only found this regex `[(|]{1}(\d+)` with the problem, he also matched something like this `Text (123 Text`.

I have an example on regex101: https://regex101.com/r/taOU8o/1

Answer (score 1):

As you have selected Javascript in the regex demo link, if a quantifier in the lookbehind [is supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) you might use:

```
(?<=\((?:\d+\|)*)\d+(?=(?:\|\d+)*\))
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is to the left is

  - `\(` Match `(`
  - `(?:\d+\|)*` Match optional repetitions of 1+ digits and `|`
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is to the right is

  - `(?:\|\d+)*` Match optional repetitions of `|` and 1+ digits
  - `\)` Match `)`
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TS9fEn/1)

```js
const regex = /(?<=\((?:\d+\|)*)\d+(?=(?:\|\d+)*\))/g;
const str = `Text (1234|5678|901) Text (222) Text (333|444)
Text (123 Text
Text |123) Text
Text |123 Text
`;

console.log(str.match(regex));
```

If you need a capture group, wrap the digits in parenthesis

```
(?<=\((?:\d+\|)*)(\d+)(?=(?:\|\d+)*\))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MkUSds/1)

Comment: This solution looks great! But unfortunately I can't use lookbehind. I have selected JavaScript in the demo, but I need the regex for an issuetracker. I can't say exactly which engine is used there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
\(\d+(?:\|\d+)*\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4eLUZ0/1). *Details*:

- `\(` - a `(` char
  -`\d+`  - one or more digits
- `(?:\|\d+)*` - zero or more reptitions of a `|` and then one or more digits
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Comment: This solution looks interesting. But I need a match with a group 1 like this: https://imgur.com/K8pnvPD.
Is it possible to realize this with the non-capturing syntax?

Comment: @rhhamburg You mentioned that these should not match `Text (123 Text`, `Text |123) Text` and `Text |123 Text`. If you need to capture the numbers inside parentheses, just use a capturing group as [shown here](https://regex101.com/r/4eLUZ0/2).

Comment: Sorry if I have expressed myself in a misleading way. In my first example https://regex101.com/r/taOU8o/1 I also have a group 1 with exactly one number per match. In your last example, I get unfortunately all numbers for a match in group 1 including the pipe.
But I need all the numbers individually and only as group 1. Is this even possible with a regex?

Comment: @rhhamburg Not in JS, yes in PHP or Java, `(?:\G(?!^)\||\()(\d+)(?=(?:\|\d+)*\))`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4eLUZ0/3).